# Travis CI: Customize os per branch

Tags: travis-ci

Is it possible to use specific OSs with specific branches in Travis CI?

I would like to configure Travis to build `master` using OSX and Linux, and to build other branches just using Linux.

The reason being that queue times for OSX are quite long (> 20m), which impacts the feedback loop when fixing bugs in the projects I work on.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

This is my current yml config file:

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 6
before_install:
  npm run uninstall && npm cache clean --force
install:
  npm install
branches:
  only:
  - master
  - develop
  - travis-ci
os:
  - linux
  - osx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to look into [Build stages](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/), in particular its capability to define conditions on things like [branch name](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/).

This is an example of how to achieve this, with (arguably) the added benefit that the `macos` stage will not even run if the `test` stage does not finish successfully:

```
language: node_js
node_js: 6
before_install:
  npm run uninstall && npm cache clean --force
install:
  npm install
branches:
  only:
  - master
  - develop
  - travis-ci
stages:
- test
- macos
jobs:
  include:
    - stage: test
    - stage: macos
      if: branch = master
      os: osx
```

Comment: To clarify, will this still enqueue a Mac build, even if it does nothing?

Comment: No job will be enqueued for MacOS if the `if:` does not match.

Comment:  I was trying to use a `branch` filter to avoid building PRs, but it seems `branch` gets set to a PR's target branch. `if: type != pull_request` did the trick.